# ¿Cómo leer los datos que se encuentran entre dos líneas que empiezan con una palabra clave?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo un código para extraer información de un archivo de salida de un programa llamado `Gaussian`. Tengo la siguiente sección del `output`:

```
Vibrational temperatures:   300 500 600 100 630
        (Kelvin)            425 689 900 325 456
                            654 897 562 148 635
                            456 888 999 789 456
Zero-point correction=      0.8998
```

Necesito sacar los valores numéricos de las temperaturas vibracionales iniciando de los que están en la misma línea que las palabras claves `"vibrational temperatures"` y terminando antes de la línea con la palabra clave de `"zero-point correction"`. Mi código sólo me entrega la primera línea donde está la palabra `"vibrational..."` y no me entrega los demás valores. He intentado varias cosas pero no queda.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Pon tu código, por favor. Aunque no funcione. Así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Puedes dar un ejemplo? Cual es el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 0):

Sólo tienes que iterar las lineas del fichero y comprobar la primera palabra de cada linea para ver si coincide con `Vibrational`, `(Kelvin)` o `Zero-point`.

Según la estructura del fichero que has mostrado, algo así debería funcionar:

```
def temperatures(path):
    f = open(path, "r")
    temps = []
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        # Insertar elementos excepto "Vibrational temperatures"
        if words[0] == "Vibrational":
            temps += words[2:]
        # Insertar elementos excepto "(Kelvin)"
        elif words[0] == "(Kelvin)":
            temps += words[1:]
        # Convertir las subcadenas a enteros y devolver
        elif words[0] == "Zero-point":
            return map(int, temps)
        # Insertar todos los elementos
        else:
            temps += words
```